# Live Query Couchbase lite peer to peer

Tags: java, android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I'm making an Android app using Couchbase. There are two devices connected to the same WiFi synchronizing data. I was using Couchbase Sync Gateway but the project needs to be peer to peer, without Sync Gateway in the middle. When I used Sync Gateway every change in one app was updated immediately. But now it's not working. The function I'm using:

```
private void showAnswers() {
    manager = DataManager.getSharedInstance(getApplicationContext());
    answersQuery = Answer.getAnswersForQuestion(manager.database, mQuestion.get_id());
    liveQuery = answersQuery.toLiveQuery();

    liveQuery.addChangeListener(new LiveQuery.ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(LiveQuery.ChangeEvent event) {
            QueryEnumerator result = event.getRows();

            Map<String, Integer> counts = getAnswerCounts(result);

            adapter = (QuestionOptionsAdapter) mQuestionOptions.getAdapter();

            adapter.setAnswerCounts(counts);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    liveQuery.start();
}
```

I don't know why the Live Query change listener isn't working. It just works once when I start the Activity.
Thank you everybody for your help.

Comment: Does your callback only run once, or does it crash?  You should check the change event type to make sure it's one you want to handle.  Code snippet looks like `if (!event.getSource().equals(query)) return;`